# how do i start the Django server directly from the Docker container folder

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have this project structure:

```
└── folder
    └── my_project_folder
        ├── my_app
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── asgi.py
        │   ├── settings.py
        │   ├── urls.py
        │   └── wsgi.py
        └── manage.py
    ├── .env.dev
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    ├── entrypoint.sh
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── Dockerfile
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python my_app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=db_admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=db_pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=some_db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apk update
RUN apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

It's working, but i dont like the line `python my_app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` in my docker-compose file.

What should i change to run `manage.py` from the docker folder?

I mean, how can i use `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` (without `my_app`)?

Comment: Do you need to change the `WORKDIR` in the Dockerfile to be in the right directory?  The `./manage.py runserver` line should probably be the image's `CMD`, not an override in the Compose file.  Also make sure your `entrypoint.sh` script ends with `exec "$@"` so this command is actually used.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm trying to repeat the training project, everything is done almost the same there, but without any problems they start the server from the same container directory where all the data is copied, I managed to do it only with an additional entry into the project folder

Answer (score 1):

In your Dockerfile, you can use `WORKDIR` to change your directory inside docker file:

```
...
COPY . .
WORKDIR "my_app"
...
```

Then you are inside `my_app` dir and you can call your command:
`python manage.py ...`